# How to use while and loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

For this assignment my teacher asked me to use while loop and the program should calculate the windchill based on the wind speed and temperature that entered by the user. Then my program will calculate and print 15 equivalent windchill temperatures for wind speeds incrementally by 1 mile per hour beginning with the entered wind speed.

**This is the expected output on the terminal when the user enters 20 as temperature and 5 for wind speed.**

> Temp is 20.0 Wind is 4.0 Windchill = 14.21540906987616
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 5.0 Windchill = 12.981228533315587
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 6.0 Windchill = 11.939602066643864
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 7.0 Windchill = 11.034900625509994
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 8.0 Windchill = 10.232972275268978
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 9.0 Windchill = 9.51125906241483
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 10.0 Windchill = 8.854038235710775
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 11.0 Windchill = 8.249889600830752
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 12.0 Windchill = 7.690242381822841
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 13.0 Windchill = 7.168491016780937
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 14.0 Windchill = 6.679431097848575
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 15.0 Windchill = 6.218885266083873
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 16.0 Windchill = 5.783446866468811
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 17.0 Windchill = 5.370299352288381
>   Temp is 20.0 Wind is 18.0 Windchill = 4.977085976370098

I tried so many times, but I keep getting endless loops and the windchill stopped calculating. It just provides the same answer. I can only made the wind speed keep increasing by 1.
I would like to ask how can I let the program only loop for 15 times based on the number that the user entered, and how can the wind chill start calculating in different answer.

This is what I am working on, (T = temp, V = wind speed, W = windchill)

```
public class windchill3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double W;
        double T;
        double V;

        T = Double.valueOf(args[0]);
        V = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
        W = 0.6215 * T - 35.75 * Math.pow(V, 0.16) + 0.4275 * T * Math.pow(V, 0.16) + 35.74;

        if (V < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        while(V>0) {
            T = Double.valueOf(args[0]);
            V = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
            W = 0.6215 * T - 35.75 * Math.pow(V, 0.16) + 0.4275 * T * Math.pow(V, 0.16) + 35.74;

            V++;

            System.out.println("The > Temperature is : " + T + " | The windspeed is: " + V + " | The windchill is: " + W);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop 15 times or based on user's input? If you want to loop 15 times only, you can try :

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 15) {
//enter your code here
}
```

The reason you keep getting endless loop is because you set the while condition for V>0, when you V++, you always get V>0 which is true, so you'll keep getting endless loop.

try :

```
while(i < 15) {
    W = 0.6215 * T - 35.75 * Math.pow(V, 0.16) + 0.4275 * T * Math.pow(V, 
        0.16) + 35.74;

    System.out.println("The > Temperature is : " + T + " | The windspeed is: 
    " + V + " | The windchill is: " + W);
    v++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I want the program loop 15 times after the user enter the wind speed.

Comment: Which means if the user type "5" for wind speed, then it will loop 15 times (each time increase the windspeed by adding 1 (6,7,8...)and the windchill will keep changing base on the equation.)

Comment: You can change your while(v>0) with while(i < 15), and dont forget to declare 'i' before you declare the while statement. Or you can see my solution I gave you:)

Comment: Hi, I tried to add int i = 0;
while(i < 15) But it can only show the windchill from 1 to 15. Since the user might type a different number, the wind speed should base on the input and then increase 15 times. What should I change to make it happen? (eg, if the user input "5" wind speed, the output should loop 15 times ( 5,6,7,8,.....19)) Moreover, the wind chill didn't change at all, I would like to know what I did wrong, Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am still having the same issue. What I want is how to get the int i loop 15 times based on the number I typed. -r.h_h

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to achieve here. You want to loop 15 times or loop based on user input (if user input 5, then loop 5 times)?

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion, I want to loop based on user input. if the user input 5 for wind speed, then the output should loop 15 times from (5 to 19 <--15 times)

Comment: This is what my assignment want me to do: instead of merely calculating the windchill equivalent temperature for the one wind speed entered by the user, your program will calculate and print 15 equivalent windchill temperatures for wind speeds incrementally by 1 mile per hour beginning with the entered wind speed.

Comment: Have you tried my edited solution? I believe I increment your V (Wind speed) at the end of while statement.

Comment: yes, everything works fine but I am still getting the endless loop,

Comment: Wait, add i++ after your v++, I forgot to put i++ hahaha. My bad:(

Comment: Yes, I did it! Thank you so so much!!